# Import/include another XUL file in XUL

Tags: import, include, xul

I am writting an Firefox add-on in XUL and I want to include another XUL file within my browser.xul. In PHP I would use something like this: include("anotherFIle.php"); but I don't know the equivalent in XUL.
What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XUL has an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/iframe) similar to the HTML iframe.  However, if you are just trying to add in some UI elements into the pre-existing UI, then look at [overlays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Overlays).

Comment: I totally missed that the OP was talking about "including" it inside of "browser.xul". Overlay sounds correct.

Comment: This worked for me to inject XUL into XUL, an iframe inside a tabpanel to render an entire independent XUL page, to share the about.xul code with options.xul, to display the About page in a more prominent location (on a tab in the options panels, rather than a context-menu item on about:addons or add-on's icon-based context-menu About menuitem).  In this use case, additional code needs to determine context and selectively show or hide "Close" button.

Answer (score 0):

Raw file-includes ala PHP cannot be done in a lot of other languages. XUL is/isn't a imperative programming language so much as a markup language -- and includes just ain't gonnna fly.

You can use an iframe to include another html page, but I don't believe you can include local files, or other XUL.

See [Using Remote XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Remote_XUL#Step_2.3a_an_iframe_for_displaying_the_web_site_content) where you'll get this handy tip:

> **Support for remote XUL has long been a potential security concern; support
>   for it was removed in Gecko 2.0. This
>   also means you can't load XUL using
>   file:// URLs.**

[XUL tutorial: content panels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Content_Panels) suggests that you can include XUL via iframe, but I don't see any working example.